# i try to addfont in jsPDF

Tags: angularjs

jsPDF PubSub Error Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded. DOMException: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.     at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:42218:52

convetToPDF(type:any){

```
let pdfTable:any
if(type == 1 ){      
  pdfTable = this.pdfTable.nativeElement
  const doc:any = new jsPDF();
  doc.addFileToVFS('Aakar.ttf', './assets/fonts/Aakar.ttf');
  doc.addFont('Aakar.ttf', 'Aakar', 'normal');
  doc.setFont('Aakar', 'normal');
  
  const specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function (element:any, renderer:any) {
      return true;
    },
  };
  doc.html(pdfTable,{
    callback: function () {
      doc.save('test.pdf');
    },
    margin: [0, 0],
    html2canvas: { scale: 0.192 },
    useCORS: true,
    x: 5,
    y: 5,
  });
  
  doc.html(pdfTable,{
    callback:  ()=> {
      const pdfData = doc.output('blob');   
      this.selectedItemPrintData = undefined
      this.itemIngredientPrintData = undefined
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', this.dataURItoPDF(pdfData,'abc'));
      if(type == 1){
        formData.append('orderId',this.orderId)
        //SENDPDF_SELECTEDITEM
        this.helper.http_post_method_requester(this.helper.POST_METHOD.SENDPDF_SELECTEDITEM,formData,true,true,true,true, (res:any) => {
          if (res.Success == true) {
          this.toster.success(res.message);               
          }else {
            this.toster.error(res.message);
          }
        });   
      }
    },
    margin: [0, 0],
    html2canvas: { scale: 0.192 },
    useCORS: true,
    x: 5,
    y: 5,
  });
}else{
  for(let x of this.finalMultiIngredients){
    let divId = x.agencyId;
    let agencyId = x.agencyId        
    const doc:any = new jsPDF();
    const specialElementHandlers = {  
      '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
      },
    };
    const pdfTable = document.getElementById(divId)?.innerHTML;

    doc.addFont('Avantika-normal.ttf', 'Avantika', 'normal');
    doc.setFont('Avantika', 'normal');

    doc.html(pdfTable,{
      callback: function () {
        doc.save('test.pdf');
      },
      margin: [0, 0],
      html2canvas: { scale: 0.192 },
      useCORS: true,
      x: 5,
      y: 5,
    });

    
      doc.html(pdfTable,{
        callback:  ()=> {
          const pdfData = doc.output('blob');
          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append('file', this.dataURItoPDF(pdfData,'Ingredient List'));
          formData.append('agencyId', agencyId);
            this.helper.http_post_method_requester(this.helper.POST_METHOD.SEND_INGREDIENT_PDF,formData,true,true,true,true, (res:any) => {
            if (res.Success == true) {
            this.toster.success(res.message);                  
            }else {
              this.toster.error(res.message);
              }
            });  
        },
        margin: [0, 0],
        html2canvas: { scale: 0.192 },
        useCORS: true,
        x: 5,
        y: 5,
      })        
  }
}
```

}
i want font in gujrati language in my pdf